# How to set label text when pressing keyboard button

Tags: vb.net

Basic question but I cant seem to find the answer anywhere.

All I want to do is if the user presses the + key on the number pad, it will set the label text to "+"

I've tried this but maybe I'm doing it wrong.

```
If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Add) Then
        Me.lblOperand.Text = "+"
    End If
```

I should mention I have this code in my textbox

```
 If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = ".")
    End If
```

Comment: In what?  A browser?  A windows app?

Comment: Just an application. Like a calculator

Comment: So what is happening?  Is it giving you an error?  Is it just not working?  Have you set breakpoints to and looked at e.KeyChar to see what it is?

Comment: e.KeyChar = "+" It said it equals the plus. but it doesn't set the label text. So is the right hand side of the argument wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the form's `KeyPreview` property set to true, you can just override the form's OnKeyDown method:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(e As KeyEventArgs)
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Add Then
    Me.lblOperand.Text = "+"
  End If
  MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Logik_ Did you set the form's KeyPreview property to true?

Comment: Yeah I Just realized that it was false. And now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hook up the KeyPress event in the code behind, set the label text to whatever the incoming event data says the key pressed was.  You may also want to look at the KeyDown event.

Comment: Updated original question.